# How to get excel functions kind of functionality in text fields?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a page which looks like below. Where some of the data are from database and there will be form fields also beside database data. All are dynamic so we need to validation for every field also.

Please check this http://jsbin.com/efinak/22/edit

```
Total Spent Cost: ((t1*100+t2*200)*x%+(t3*110)*y%)spent for A + spent for B

Client : A

product        No of Hours      Avg Rate/Hour       Cost
A1                  t1              100             t1*100
A2                  t2              200             t2*200

Total Cost:                                         t1*100+t2*200
Percentage(%):                                          x
Spent Cost:                                         (t1*100+t2*200)*x%

Client : B

product        No of Hours      Avg Rate/Hour       Cost
B1                  t3              110             t3*100


Total Cost:                                         t3*110
Percentage(%):                                        y
Spent Cost:                                         (t3*110)*y%
```

In the above example client, product and No of hours will come from database. I kept a text field for Avg Rate/Hour and a text field for Cost also.

Why i mentioned in the question excel kind of funcitonality is i will explain here.
If suppose i set Avg Rate/Hour text field then automatically cost should be calcualted without any redirecting. In the same way if you set cost Avg Rate/ hour should be calculated automatically.

Once costs are calculated Total cost should be calculated automatically.Like above percentage is also having a text field which will also set by user with some value. Based on that you need to calucalte spent cost.

I need to this thing for every cleint. Once after every cleint's spent cost calculated automatically total spent cost also should be calcualted on the fly.

I need ideas and if possible more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery script for this. I take short example from which you can know basic logic behind this. Suppose you have 4 fields.
A, B, C and D with appropriate class name.

Here A and B are from database, C is input field, and D is input field for final answer.
You can calculate D automatically as following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.class_C').live('change', function() {
          var A = $('.class_A').val();
          var B = $('.class_B').val();
          var C = $('.class_C').val();

          // Calculate D as per A, B and C.
          var D = A + B * C / 50;

          // Put new value in to D field.
          $('.class_D').val(D);
     });
})
```

**EDIT::**

Check : http://jsbin.com/efinak/27/edit

```
$('input[name="quantity"]').change(function() {   
  var total = 0;
  $('input[name="price"]').map(function(i,n) {
    total += Number(n.value);
  });
  $('input[name="total"]').val(total);
});
```

Comment: hey can you check my jsfiddle link

Comment: Check http://jsbin.com/efinak/27/edit.

What you need is to look at, $.map function.

Comment: Till now what we did is when we set unit price automatically total prices calculated......now i need reverse when i set price that should calculate unit price.

Comment: Reverse can be done using,


$("input[name='price']").change(function() {
    var newvalue = $(this).val();                  $(this).parent().parent().find("input[name='unitprice']").val(newvalue);
  });

Comment: I need to check which one is set if quantity set then calculate price and total all prices otherwise if prices set calculate quantity. Can you implement this one......

Comment: Using previous comment code, when you change price, it will change unit price for that row. To change unit price as per quantity, make var newvalue = $(this).val() * Quantity.



http://jsbin.com/efinak/51/edit

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same aggregate functions for each client, you could create a javascript class and attach it to each table, binding the calculations to the change events of the input fields.

You could make a jquery plugin kind of like this: (i didn't come close to finishing it, but its a start)

you would have to add classes to each row and item that allows you to identify it easier in the dom with jquery also, but ultimately it will turn out cleaner.

```
(function($){

   var Client = function(el){
       var $table = $(el);
     $.each($('.product-row'),function(row){
       var $row = $(row);
       //do the product total calculations here and bind it
     });
     $.each($('.total-row'),function(row){
       //bind your total calculation
     });
      //do this for discount and final rows also 


       $table.data('Client', this);
   };

   $.fn.client = function(){
      return this.each(function(){
         (new Client(this));
      });
   };


})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.client-table').client();
});
```

Comment: i can elaborate if you are interested in using this solution

Comment: I am interested in solution using Jquery which tried in my example link